# Making An Element Stretch Across The Entire Screen

Tags: html, css, navbar, blogger

I would like to have my menu bar across the entire screen, currently it is in the middle with white space on either side. I would like the bar to be stretched along the top of the page but for it to not "hover". I have tried the position:fixed and that has achieved the look of the menu that I want however I don't want the menu bar to be fixed to the top of the screen as the reader scrolls down the page. The URL to my blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com and I have included the css coding for the menu bar below :

```
#topdropcont { 
width:100%;
height:45px;
padding: 5.5px 0 0 0;
z-index:100;
top:-2px;
left: 0px;
position:absolute;
background:#f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: You will need to take your menu out of `<div class="content-outer">` which currently has a max-width on it. It looks like there is already another `<div class="navbar section">` built into your theme, you just aren't using it.

You could also rewite the page CSSs to add the max-width somewhere else, but thats a bit more involved than this question suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Change `position:absolute;` to `position: fixed;`

The other option is running the following jQuery script that calculates the width using JS

```
$("#wctopdropcont").css('left',($(document).width() - 1080) / 2 * -1).width($(document).width());
```

Comment: I have considered that however I don't want the menu to be fixed to the top of the page as readers scroll down.

Comment: Note that if you're setting `position:static;` then the element get's displayed as you scrolling down the page and it fits to the browser window

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell (and assuming I understand how you want your page to look), the problem isn't in your `topdropcount`, it's in your `content-outer`, which appears to specify a space that's 1080 pixels wide.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want a fixed header you have to change the position attribute of div.content-outer & .fauxborder-left to position: static (actually relative).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're using a relative width (100%) inside of a defined width container (.content-outer{1080px;}).  You can see how this works by adding a larger relative width to your #topdropcont. (e.g. #topdropcont {width: 120%;}).

You can easily solve this by moving the markup of the menu outside of that container.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Matthew Darnell said your class `content-outer` has the following css styles `min-width: 1080px` and `max-width: 1080px` so having a `width` of `100%` on your menu will give it a `width` of `1080px`. If you don't want to move your menu outside of `countent-outer`, you can make the following changes to your css:

1) Remove `min-width: 1080px` and `max-width: 1080px` from `.content-outer`
2) Add `min-width: 1080px`, `max-width: 1080px` and `margin: 0 auto` to your `header` tag and to `.main-outer`

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since first parent element of the Menu that has 100% width is `.content`, make sure it has `position: relative`, than make sure all other parent Menu elements **have no position set**. Than you can set your menu container to absolute positioning.

Final CSS should be:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
}

.content-outer {
    /* REMOVE: position: relative; */
}

.fauxborder-left {
    /* REMOVE: position: relative; */
}

#wctopdropcont {
    position: absolute;
    /* Fading script should be removed...
       it changes opacity and display, so: */
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

What you get after is this:

[image]